# Concatenation string with variable in smarty

Tags: smarty

I need in smarty template to transmit to function concatenated string constant with variable value, How can i do it?

some example code:
`{$obj->calledFunc('string const').$var}`
but . operator doesn't work

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the [cat modifier](http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.modifier.cat.php):

```
{$obj->calledFunc('string const')|cat:$var}
```

Comment: This just saved me a huge amount of time/hassle, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

You can use concatenation like this:

```
{'my_string'|cat:$my_variable|cat:'concat_string'}
```